# Trying to print prime numbers from 1 to 1000 separated by with &. The error is "ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 28: Data too long for column 'p' at row 1"

Tags: mysql, primes

```
delimiter $$
create procedure a()
begin
declare x int default 3;
declare n int default 1;
declare y int default 0;
declare p varchar(2000) default '2';
case 
when x<=1000 then 
    while x<=1000 do
        while n<=x do
            if x%n=0  then set y=y+1;
            else set y=y;
            end if;
            set n = n+1;
                if y=2 then set p = concat(p ,'&' ,x );
    else set n=n;
    end if;
        end while;
    set n=1;
    set y=0;
    set x=x+1;
    end while;
else set y=0;
end case;
select p ;
end $$
call a();
```

I tried all the way that I could to find the error. I found many online resources where new solution exists, but I would like to find out the mistake within my code such that I could learn from mistakes.

Comment: `CASE` statements contain `WHEN` clauses, not `WHILE`. You should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `x%n`, not `x%y`. This is another excellent example of why it's important to use meaningful variable names instead of single-character identifiers. Beware that `n` should be reinitialized before that inner loop, and should _not_ be zero.

Comment: Barmar , It helps. Thank you. I have just modified the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems.

First, and the direct cause of your error, in mysql `+` is a numeric operation.  To do string concatenation, do:

```
set p = concat(p, '&', x);
```

Second, you need to set n to 1 each iteration through the `while x` loop.  As is, it reaches 1001 for the first x value and the `while n<=1000` loop is effectively skipped for later values.